# How Insert Detail Rows As Columns In DevExpress Reports

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I am using DevExpress reports and I need to insert two detail rows into one row, for example like this (1 column for each detail row):

```
------------------------------------
     Detail1   |      Detail2
------------------------------------
```

Currently when I insert detail row 2, it is insert under the detail row 1 for example this:

```
-----------------------------------
           Detail1
-----------------------------------
           Detail2
-----------------------------------
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Not clear why you need this. Why not insert all what you need in one detail and insert two tables in one Detail if you want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`XRSubreport`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/clsDevExpressXtraReportsUIXRSubreporttopic) objects for show two details in one row by placing two subreports side-by-side<sup>0</sup>. So, just put two `XRSubreport` objects to your `DetailBand` and use `XRSubreport.BeforePrint` event handler to provide the details data for subreports<sup>1</sup>.
Here is example:

```cs
public void ShowReport()
{
    var masters = new List<Master>();

    var random = new Random();

    for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++)
    {
        var master = new Master() { ID = index, Name = "Master_" + index };

        var detailCount = random.Next(1, 10);
        for (int detailIndex = 0; detailIndex < detailCount; detailIndex++)
        {
            var detail0 = new Detail0() { ID = detailIndex, Name = "Detail_0_" + detailIndex };
            master.Details0.Add(detail0);
        }

        detailCount = random.Next(1, 10);
        for (int detailIndex = 0; detailIndex < detailCount; detailIndex++)
        {
            var detail1 = new Detail1() { ID = detailIndex, Name = "Detail_1_" + detailIndex };
            master.Details1.Add(detail1);
        }

        masters.Add(master);
    }

    var report = new XtraReport();

    var detailBand = CreateDetailBand(report, masters);
    detailBand.HeightF = 40;

    var detailReport0 = new XtraReport();
    CreateDetailBand(detailReport0, null);

    var subReport0 = new XRSubreport() { LocationF = new PointF(20, 20), WidthF = 150, ReportSource = detailReport0 };
    subReport0.BeforePrint += (s, e) =>
    {
        var currentReport = ((XRSubreport)s);
        var master = ((Master)currentReport.Report.GetCurrentRow());
        currentReport.ReportSource.DataSource = master.Details0;
    };

    detailBand.Controls.Add(subReport0);

    var detailReport1 = new XtraReport();
    CreateDetailBand(detailReport1, null);

    var subReport1 = new XRSubreport() { LocationF = new PointF(170, 20), WidthF = 150, ReportSource = detailReport1 };
    subReport1.BeforePrint += (s, e) =>
    {
        var currentReport = ((XRSubreport)s);
        var master = ((Master)currentReport.Report.GetCurrentRow());
        currentReport.ReportSource.DataSource = master.Details1;
    };

    detailBand.Controls.Add(subReport1);

    report.DataSource = masters;

    report.ShowRibbonPreview();
}

public DetailBand CreateDetailBand(XtraReport report, object DataSource)
{
    var detailBand = new DetailBand() { HeightF = 20 };

    var label = new XRLabel();
    label.DataBindings.Add(new XRBinding("Text", DataSource, "ID"));

    detailBand.Controls.Add(label);

    label = new XRLabel() { LeftF = 30 };
    label.DataBindings.Add(new XRBinding("Text", DataSource, "Name"));

    detailBand.Controls.Add(label);

    report.Bands.Add(detailBand);

    return detailBand;
}

public class Master
{
    public Master()
    {
        Details0 = new List<Detail0>();
        Details1 = new List<Detail1>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Detail0> Details0 { get; private set; }
    public List<Detail1> Details1 { get; private set; }
}

public class Detail0
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Detail1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

<sup><sup>0</sup> [How to: Create a Side-by-Side Report](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4787)</sup>
<sup><sup>1</sup> [How to: Create a Master-Detail Report using Subreports](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument4629)</sup>